# cannot import name reader from partially initialized module easyocr most likely due to a circular import

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

**My error is explained in the title.How can I solve this?I cant seem to find any circular imports but I am getting the error anyways.Is it bad designing of the module or am I doing something wrong?**

```
import easyocr
import argparse

import cv2
def cleanup_text(text):
    # strip out non-ASCII text so we can draw the text on the image
    # using OpenCV
    return "".join([c if ord(c) < 128 else "" for c in text]).strip()
    # construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to input image to be OCR'd")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--langs", type=str, default="en",
    help="comma separated list of languages to OCR")
ap.add_argument("-g", "--gpu", type=int, default=-1,
    help="whether or not GPU should be used")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# break the input languages into a comma separated list
langs = args["langs"].split(",")
print("[INFO] OCR'ing with the following languages: {}".format(langs))
# load the input image from disk
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
# OCR the input image using EasyOCR
print("[INFO] OCR'ing input image...")
reader = easyocr.Reader(langs, gpu=args["gpu"] > 0)
results = reader.readtext(image)

# loop over the results
for (bbox, text, prob) in results:
    # display the OCR'd text and associated probability
    print("[INFO] {:.4f}: {}".format(prob, text))
    # unpack the bounding box
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = bbox
    tl = (int(tl[0]), int(tl[1]))
    tr = (int(tr[0]), int(tr[1]))
    br = (int(br[0]), int(br[1]))
    bl = (int(bl[0]), int(bl[1]))
    # cleanup the text and draw the box surrounding the text along
    # with the OCR'd text itself
    text = cleanup_text(text)
    cv2.rectangle(image, tl, br, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(image, text, (tl[0], tl[1] - 10),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 255, 0), 2)
# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm a bit late, but I think your code file name is the same as the module name (like easyocr.py), if yes then you can fix this issue by renaming your coding file to any other name.

Comment: Renaming the file worked for me.